# Trying to use a access a variable in another scope after render_template() (Flask)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I'm trying to create a web app that uses a form (WTForms) to take two svn urls and do something/displays them. It will have an update button that if clicked will **ONLY** display a table with info along with **another submit button** that does another function (using `show=True` given to render_template)

`views.py`:

```
@app.route('/test4', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test4():

    form1=SVN_Path()
    form2=Inputs()
    if request.method=="POST":
        if request.form.get('updatepaths')=='Update' and form1.validate_on_submit():
        --> basepath=createDir()
            svn_url1 = form1.svn_url1.data
            svn_url2 = form1.svn_url2.data
        --> prev_pdf=PDF_List(svn_url1,basepath,'prev')  #function that generates a list
            new_pdf=PDF_List(svn_url2,basepath,'new')   #function that generates a list
            options=[("None","None")]+[(pdf,pdf) for pdf in new_pdf]
            for sub_form in form2.files:
                sub_form.choices= options
                sub_form.default="None"
            return render_template('test4.html',form1=form1,form2=form2,show=True,numfiles=len(prev_pdf),pdflist=prev_pdf)
        elif request.form.get('batchfiles')=='Submit':
            #I WANT TO USE PREV_PDF AND BASEPATH IN THIS PART BUT IT IS OUT OF SCOPE
    else:
        return render_template('test4.html',form1=form1,form2=form2)
```

The `elif` portion : `elif request.form.get('batchfiles')=='Submit':`
is the second submit that will appear ONLY when the first submit is clicked, however,

**THE PROBLEM ARISES WHEN**: in that section of the code I want to use basepath and prev_pdf which is out of the scope since I returned render_template at the end of the first `if` statement. Also I can't access form1.svn_url1.data anymore either so I can't just recall the function.

I just can't think of a way to format the code or a solution that will solve my problem so any help  is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is only possible if you store `prev_pdf` somewhere that can be accessed in the next request. I will suggest either storing the list itself (`prev_pdf`) in Flask Session or storing the `svn_url1` so you can regenerate the list on the second request. See [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions) example of how to use FLask Sessions.

The reason you need to save that data is as you have discovered, each HTTP request is completely self contained and "isolated" from the previous requests so the only way to communicate between requests is to either pass the information you want from the client each time, or save that information on the server side and access it with each request.